# Can I make fabric use `dzdo su -` instead of sudo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

We have some older systems that don't actually have `sudo` installed, they have `dzdo`, which is a Centrify thing. It looks like we're pretty limited in what we can do, basically `dzdo su -` is it. So we ssh in, run `dzdo su -` to gain root, and then do our stuff.

Is there a way to make fabric do this?

I've tried

```
from fabric.api import settings

def as_root():
    with settings(sudo_prefix='dzdo su -'):
        sudo('whoami')
```

and `dzdo` and `dzdo su` and... none of these approaches work.

Is there a way that I can use Fabric for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but this is what worked for me:

```
def as_root():
    env.sudo_prefix = "/usr/bin/dzdo -s"
    sudo('whoami')
```

Or, with your approach:

```
def as_root():
    with settings(sudo_prefix='/usr/bin/dzdo -s'):
        sudo('whoami')
```